# Setting up email action for Task Scheduler with PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-task-scheduler

I am setting up Windows Task with PowerShell. I am using `New-ScheduledTaskAction` command to setup an action but couldn't find the option to send an email.

Is it possible to set email action with PowerShell?

Answer (score 0):

Within your Powershell script you can use the Send-MailMessage command to send email, see here for the syntax.

https://ss64.com/ps/send-mailmessage.html

Just relies on having an SMTP server to send through obviously, but you can construct the subject and body content to be included as variables within your script (eg have a string variable with the content you want to include, and then use that variable when calling the command), plus include attachments if relevant.

Comment: That can be done. But I would like to setup email task which is a feature of Task Scheduler